# Git Rebase: Merge branch before last commit

Tags: git

I have the following scenario:

**Branch Feature**

```
A - X (HEAD)
```

**Branch Master** (Have some new stuff since branch creation)

```
A - B - C
```

If I do git merge (on top of branch feature) I have:

```
A - X - B - C
```

Is there anyway to do some sort of rebase to get A - B - C - X? The changes in the master branch could be fast-fowarded if I didn't already make that commit, so I would like to have a more compreensive git log at that branch.

The real use-case (and maybe I'm doing a bad pratice) is: I create a branch for developing a new feature from the master branch. After doing some commits, someone tell-me that the master branch had a bug that was already fixed, so I have to get that changes from master too. Git merge, works fine, but If I do a git log later I see tons of unrelated commits on top of my commits, and it get a little messy to show what changes I've done in my branch.

Comment: This sounds like a textbook case for `git rebase master`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I find funny that you asked "is there any sort of rebase to get A - B - C - X?" when in fact, that's exactly what rebase do. `git rebase` replays the branch commits on top of another commit, in your case, it could move X on top of C. It seems you aren't still grasping the basic git concepts, I'd recommend rereading the sections about branching/merging/rebasing of whatever book/documentation you used to learn git.

Comment: I had to break it to you, but all you need to do is `git rebase master`.

Comment: LOL, sorry guys I feel very dumb now. :( I read all the section about git rebase and missed something very badly. After reading the man pages for git-rebase, I got it now. @.@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the original state of your repo is as follows:

```
  B - C [master]
 / 
A - - - X [feature]
```

Now, if you do a merge (of `feature` into `master`), you'll end up, *not* with

```
A - X - B - C
```

as you wrote in your question, but with

```
  B - C - D [HEAD,master]
 /       /
A - - - X [feature]
```

Instead, you should do the following

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

and you'll end up with

```
A - B - C [master]
         \
          X' [HEAD,feature]
```

as desired `:)`

Recommended reading about `git rebase`:

- http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up.html
- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Answer (score 1):

Well, as my colleagues above said, `git rebase master` does exactly that. The git-book explain thats VERY well (and somehow I missed it. d'uh!):

> git rebase [...] works by going to the common ancestor of the two branches (the one
>   you’re on and the one you’re rebasing onto), getting the diff
>   introduced by each commit of the branch you’re on, saving those diffs
>   to temporary files, resetting the current branch to the same commit as
>   the branch you are rebasing onto, and finally applying each change in
>   turn